# PHP unlink file still showing until manually reloading page

Tags: php

I got source code from GitHub which has an **index.php** file and some inc extensions, I have created a new delete.inc extension with the following contents:

```
<?php

if ( !empty( $_GET['trash'] ) ) {

$trash = $targetdir . '/' . $_GET['trash'];

    if ( file_exists( $trash ) ) {
    
    unlink($trash);
    
    //header('Refresh: 1; url=index.php');
    //header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    //header("Location: index.php");
    //header("location:updateurl?id=0");
    //header("Refresh:0");  
    //getMedia($targetdir);
    

    
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit();
}
}
```

The line `unlink($trash);` deletes the unwanted image however the image is still showing until I manual reload the page, I tried to reload it using code after deleting the file with the 6 commented out lines but non seem to work, I even tried to call the `getMedia($targetdir);` function from the index.php file to reload media (without the deleted image file) but no luck there. The code posted is triggered by a button click.

Comment: Think about what happens if someone puts `?trash=../../some-super-important-file` in that url...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that it only refreshes on manual reload, it means that you are essentially sending an AJAX request to the PHP page that's removing the file. Possible solutions:

## Refreshing the page via PHP

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

## Refreshing the page via Javascript

You can execute

```
window.location.reload();
```

in your AJAX callback.

## Requesting the existing files with AJAX

This is the best approach, but it is labor-intensive. You will send a request via AJAX to get the files that exist, get a response and rerender the content on the page. You can speculate in using the AJAX request you already have to make it respond with the file list and then refresh things on the client-side if you do not want to send two requests to the server during the process instead of a single one.